# Matlab code not working, trying to filter 2 arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, filter

How can i  Plot an array in a graph against its order in array in matlab ??

Example : x= [6,10,12,20] point 1 become 6:1 and point 3= 12:3 for example even after i remove some elemets from this array i want to preserve same order

example of what am trying to do here is to remove all values bellow mean while keep order cause it represent the time in sec's (this is from video processing code):

```
m=mean(amp);
for i=totalframes
    if (amp(i) >= m)
        time(i)=i/framerate;
    end
end
amp(amp >= m) = [];
time(time > 0) = [];
figure, plot(time,amp) %% plot my curve
```

P.s: time and amp array was created by Zeros earlier in my code..

Thanks

Comment: Is there an easier way to do it >???? please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove all values below the mean `m` you should do:

```
inds=(amp<m)  %% find where amp is lower than m
amp(inds) = [];  %% remove corresponding amp
time(inds) = []; %% remove corresponding time
figure, plot(time,amp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change design of `x` from `[6; 10; 12; 20]` to `[1 6; 2 10; 3 12; 4 20]` and traverse this array deleting rows that you dont want then you will have result array with indexes.